# Performing an action when the "tab" is selected

Tags: java, swing, events, user-interface, tabs

I am creating a JDBC application, which the user interface consists of 2 tabs. First tab is to insert data, second is to update. When the user click on the second tab, I need to execute the method "getUpdates()". I need to execute this method each time that the user navigates to this second tab. How can I do it?

(For more information, these two tabs are separate Java beans, which extends the class "Common GUI". "Common GUI" extends from JPanel. They get displayed in class "Main GUI", as tabs)

Please help!

Comment: I hope you won't query the database on the Event Dispatch Thread, or you will end up with an unresponsive UI

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using `JTabbedPane` then you could use `JTabbedPane#addChangeListener` as seen in this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JTabbedPaneaddChangeListenerChangeListenerl.htm)